# How to publish **Attachments** (pdf, xls, xml..) into **kafka topic*

Tags: apache-kafka

How to publish **Attachments** (pdf, xls, xml, jpg..) to **kafka topic**. Currently we are publihing to Kafka in AVRO format. AVRO supports to attach file into that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka topics hold information as binary data. So in order to send records to kafka they need to be serialized to binary format and deserialized when read from any topic to correct format.

Avro makes this operation easy and forward/backward compatible(with configuration and schema). But I don't think avro supports file's as input.More than one format can be used in kafka cluster. The best you can do might be to create a custom serializer/deserializer for your use case where serializer will read data and convert it to binary vice versa. And use it when inserting/reading from that particular topic(s).

Also if you are using Schema Registry with AVRO you can't use it with your custom serializer/deserializer.

Comment: Hi Yam Thanks, so we cant use Attachments with AVRO serde? We need to seperate topic only for Attachments with ByteArraySerializer or Custom SerDe?

Comment: personally I would use one topic for object that would hold both object data and attachments as byte array since it would be easier to get the whole data, otherwise you would need to stitch your attachment info with other info from the original object.